# How to interchange D3DImage between a WPF application and Windows (for Copy/Paste)?

Tags: wpf, interop, bitmap, direct3d

I'm being working in making copy and paste operations on my diagramming application.
Therefore, I need to...

- Convert a WPF Bitmap to a D3DImage (for later implement "Copy"), and
- Convert a D3DImage to a WPF Bitmap (for later implement "Paste").

Notice that this requieres "Interop" between the WPF Application and the native Win-32.

How to do this, as short as possible (two functions, ideally)?

Comment: Is that native application yours too? (Can you modify it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably found your answer in the past half year but here is how to convert a D3DImage in WPF to BitmapSource (I used vb.net in this case):

```
Public Function GetCurrentImage() As BitmapSource

        Dim width As Integer = D3DImage.PixelWidth
        Dim height As Integer = D3DImage.PixelHeight

        Dim dv As New DrawingVisual()
        Using dc As DrawingContext = dv.RenderOpen()
            dc.DrawImage(D3DImage, New Rect(0, 0, width, height))
        End Using

        Dim rtb As New RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        rtb.Render(dv)

        Return BitmapFrame.Create(rtb)
    End Function
```

You can find it in C# in the WPFMediaKit.

Comment: Yes, it took me very try/error with many conversions to get the functionality and still now I have to test again uncommon format variatns (such as different dpi). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by D3DImage?

There is a 'Control'/Surface in WPF that is named D3DImage but it feels as if you are referring to a bitmap format. Are you trying to put the data on the clipboard? If so you won't need interop. Just use the Clipboard API to put the image on the clipboard and read it from the clipboard.

Comment: D3DImage is the type of an external (non WPF, so a Win-32) image intended to be pasted (with Clipboard.GetImage() after copying from let's say Paint.NET) but that I cannot convert to a valid WPF BitmapImage (it shows a black rectangle instead). The MSDN documentation is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx

Comment: Are you copying to the correct buffer? Can you show us some code?